Ошибка при работе с Airflow и Jupyter Notebook
Я установил Airflow на wsl. Поднял сервис и написал первый dag, dag я написал в jupyter notebook который также установил на wsl в необходимую среду. Но Airfow не видит мой dag  и при отработке следующей команды: airflow dags list-import-errors. Выдает следующую ошибку:

Хотя я не создавал файл untiled-chekpoint.py - это jupyter сам типо контрольной точки сохраняет, не могу понять как решить данную проблему, подскажите пожалуйста.
